# How to get a column and line from textfile. php/html

Tags: html, file, text

If i have a textfile called text.txt, inside the textfile at column 2 line 6 there is one word "help" how do i read that word and print it out with php/html?

Comment: You can't with pure HTML, you would need some scripting language.

Comment: If the textfile is on the server, you'll have to use a server-side language to read it and then write to your page. HTML is only for markup and can't access files in any way.

Comment: @brbcoding It can be done client side with js, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533018/how-to-read-a-text-file-from-server-using-javascript

Comment: @jtheman that's true, AJAX would be one way to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With HTML it is impossible. You need to use PHP or other language.

Using PHP

```
<?php
$arr = file ("text.txt");
substr($arr[5],2,4);
?>
```

or if you want exact word to be found.

```
<?php
$arr = file ("text.txt");
preg_match('/help/', $arr[5], $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

http://php.net/manual/pl/function.file.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

Need to use php like here:
http://www.html.net/tutorials/php/lesson15.php
Just insert php code inside your html page. Use array and string operations to do what you need.