# I want to display the contents of a Word file in html without installing the software. How can I display files like. docs or .xlsx on my web page?

Tags: html

I want to display the contents of a Word file in html without installing the software. How can I display files like. docs or .xlsx on my web page?

```
<embed src="testdoc.docx"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: [How do I render a Word document (.doc, .docx) in the browser using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript)

It's pretty old. But for what I know of you still cannot do it.

However, it's a little different with excel files. If you convert it to CSV you can use xmlHttpRequest, see this answer: [Display CSV file in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684370/display-csv-file-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is nothing to render .doc or .xls file in the browser. However you can use frames and Google Doc.to show/display the content of document

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://remote.url.tld/path/to/document.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```