# Show real time data from local xml tag on a web page

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I've got a local XML file constantly updated by 3rd. What I would like to achieve is a web page that constantly read and show one xml tag without refresh the page. Plus I would like to trigger an event when XML value change.

What language I should use? I've read something about ajax, it could be ok to build a script like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can not read file from filesystem using only javascript [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript)
2. You need a web server like Nginx or Apache HTTP which will serve the file to a client using http request. [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533018/how-to-read-a-text-file-from-server-using-javascript)
3. Finally you will need to implement poll request using ajax on client-side to check the file once per specified interval (for example 10 seconds) [related post](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

NOTE: Check jQuery, it can simplify your life